# How to sort column values in csv file using shell script or command?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a csv file with the below values:

```
IP        Code
10.0.0.1  200
10.2.0.1  400
10.3.0.2  100
10.2.3.1  201
```

I want to extract IPs whose code is either 200 or more than that. What can be the simplest way to do it in linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bash` solution:

```sh
tail -n +2 file.csv |
while read -r ip code; do ((code >= 200)) && echo "$ip"; done
```

```
10.0.0.1
10.2.0.1
10.2.3.1
```

Answer (score 3):

Is `awk` an option?

```sh
awk 'NR>1 && $2>=200 {print $1}' file.csv
```

```
10.0.0.1
10.2.0.1
10.2.3.1
```